# wglGetProcAddress returning NULL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, wgl

I am using `wlgGetProcAddress` to get functions using a context created with `wglCreateContext`.  I have set the context with `wglMakeCurrent`.  I get a valid function pointer for `glGetStringi`, but I get `NULL` for `glGetString`.  I thought that `glGetString` and `glGetStringi` were introduced in the same version of OpenGL (1.0).  Any ideas why I am getting this `NULL`?

```
const GLubyte* (*glGetString)(GLenum);
const GLubyte* (*glGetStringi)(GLenum, GLuint);
glGetString = reinterpret_cast<decltype(glGetString)>(wglGetProcAddress("glGetString"));
glGetStringi = reinterpret_cast<decltype(glGetStringi)>(wglGetProcAddress("glGetStringi"));
```

In case it matters, I have a Radeon HD 7950 with driver version 13.251.0.0.

Comment: What the profile of the context you're creating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glGetStringi` was introduced much later than 1.0 - I believe it is 3.3. To make things worse, on core 3.3+ profile you can't use `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`, but required to use `glGetStringi`, which is unavailable for lower profile versions.

MSDN documentation says `wglGetProcAddress` only returns addresses for extension functions. And 'extension' in their terms is everything that is not in GL 1.1.

Please read https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/168281-Can-t-get-wglGetProcAddress-to-work-in-opengl-3-1